# Como poderia otimizar este código PHP JS?

Tags: php, javascript, otimização, google-charts

Tenho este código em PHP e JS que busca no BD as visitas que o site X recebeu no mês atual e joga em um gráfico do Google Charts.

Apesar de estar funcional e me servir bem até então, eu fico incomodado com a aparência e o tamanho disto e gostaria muito de saber se teria alguma forma melhor de executar essa mesma tarefa com um código bem mais limpo e inteligente.

Desde já agradeço qualquer contribuição.

**Segue abaixo trecho em PHP:**

```
<?php
$meses = array(
    '01'=>'Janeiro',
    '02'=>'Fevereiro',
    '03'=>'Março',
    '04'=>'Abril',
    '05'=>'Maio',
    '06'=>'Junho',
    '07'=>'Julho',
    '08'=>'Agosto',
    '09'=>'Setembro',
    '10'=>'Outubro',
    '11'=>'Novembro',
    '12'=>'Dezembro'
);

$mes_atual_nome = $meses[date('m')];

$mes_atual = date('m');
$ano_atual = date('Y');

$ReadViewsDia_1 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '01' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_1 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_1);
if ($numViewsDia_1 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_1 = $numViewsDia_1; else: $TotalViewsdia_1 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_2 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '02' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_2 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_2);
if ($numViewsDia_2 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_2 = $numViewsDia_2; else: $TotalViewsdia_2 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_3 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '03' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_3 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_3);
if ($numViewsDia_3 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_3 = $numViewsDia_3; else: $TotalViewsdia_3 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_4 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '04' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_4 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_4);
if ($numViewsDia_4 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_4 = $numViewsDia_4; else: $TotalViewsdia_4 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_5 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '05' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_5 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_5);
if ($numViewsDia_5 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_5 = $numViewsDia_5; else: $TotalViewsdia_5 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_6 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '06' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_6 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_6);
if ($numViewsDia_6 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_6 = $numViewsDia_6; else: $TotalViewsdia_6 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_7 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '07' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_7 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_7);
if ($numViewsDia_7 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_7 = $numViewsDia_7; else: $TotalViewsdia_7 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_8 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '08' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_8 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_8);
if ($numViewsDia_8 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_8 = $numViewsDia_8; else: $TotalViewsdia_8 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_9 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '09' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_9 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_9);
if ($numViewsDia_9 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_9 = $numViewsDia_9; else: $TotalViewsdia_9 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_10 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '10' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_10 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_10);
if ($numViewsDia_10 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_10 = $numViewsDia_10; else: $TotalViewsdia_10 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_11 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '11' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_11 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_11);
if ($numViewsDia_11 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_11 = $numViewsDia_11; else: $TotalViewsdia_11 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_12 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '12' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_12 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_12);
if ($numViewsDia_12 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_12 = $numViewsDia_12; else: $TotalViewsdia_12 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_13 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '13' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_13 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_13);
if ($numViewsDia_13 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_13 = $numViewsDia_13; else: $TotalViewsdia_13 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_14 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '14' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_14 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_14);
if ($numViewsDia_14 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_14 = $numViewsDia_14; else: $TotalViewsdia_14 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_15 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '15' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_15 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_15);
if ($numViewsDia_15 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_15 = $numViewsDia_15; else: $TotalViewsdia_15 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_16 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '16' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_16 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_16);
if ($numViewsDia_16 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_16 = $numViewsDia_16; else: $TotalViewsdia_16 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_17 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '17' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_17 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_17);
if ($numViewsDia_17 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_17 = $numViewsDia_17; else: $TotalViewsdia_17 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_18 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '18' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_18 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_18);
if ($numViewsDia_18 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_18 = $numViewsDia_18; else: $TotalViewsdia_18 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_19 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '19' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_19 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_19);
if ($numViewsDia_19 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_19 = $numViewsDia_19; else: $TotalViewsdia_19 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_20 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '20' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_20 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_20);
if ($numViewsDia_20 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_20 = $numViewsDia_20; else: $TotalViewsdia_20 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_21 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '21' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_21 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_21);
if ($numViewsDia_21 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_21 = $numViewsDia_21; else: $TotalViewsdia_21 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_22 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '22' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_22 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_22);
if ($numViewsDia_22 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_22 = $numViewsDia_22; else: $TotalViewsdia_22 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_23 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '23' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_23 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_23);
if ($numViewsDia_23 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_23 = $numViewsDia_23; else: $TotalViewsdia_23 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_24 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '24' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_24 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_24);
if ($numViewsDia_24 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_24 = $numViewsDia_24; else: $TotalViewsdia_24 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_25 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '25' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_25 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_25);
if ($numViewsDia_25 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_25 = $numViewsDia_25; else: $TotalViewsdia_25 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_26 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '26' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_26 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_26);
if ($numViewsDia_26 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_26 = $numViewsDia_26; else: $TotalViewsdia_26 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_27 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '27' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_27 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_27);
if ($numViewsDia_27 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_27 = $numViewsDia_27; else: $TotalViewsdia_27 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_28 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '28' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_28 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_28);
if ($numViewsDia_28 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_28 = $numViewsDia_28; else: $TotalViewsdia_28 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_29 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '29' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_29 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_29);
if ($numViewsDia_29 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_29 = $numViewsDia_29; else: $TotalViewsdia_29 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_30 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '30' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_30 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_30);
if ($numViewsDia_30 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_30 = $numViewsDia_30; else: $TotalViewsdia_30 = '0'; endif;

$ReadViewsDia_31 = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '31' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
$numViewsDia_31 = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia_31);
if ($numViewsDia_31 > 0): $TotalViewsdia_31 = $numViewsDia_31; else: $TotalViewsdia_31 = '0'; endif;
```

**Abaixo o trecho em JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Dias', {type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}, 'Todas as visitas', 'Visitas únicas ao site'],
        ['Dia 1', '', <?=$TotalViewsdia_1 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 2', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_2 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 3', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_3 ?>,       0],
        ['Dia 4', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_4 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 5', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_5 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 6', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_6 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 7', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_7 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 8', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_8 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 9', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_9 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 10', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_10 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 11', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_11 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 12', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_12 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 13', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_13 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 14', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_14 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 15', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_15 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 16', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_16 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 17', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_17 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 18', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_18 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 19', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_19 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 20', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_20 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 21', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_21 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 22', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_22 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 23', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_23 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 24', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_24 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 25', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_25 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 26', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_26 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 27', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_27 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 28', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_28 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 29', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_29 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 30', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_30 ?>,      0],
        ['Dia 31', '',  <?=$TotalViewsdia_31 ?>,      0]
    ]);

    var options = {
        chartArea : { top:20 },
        vAxis: {minValue: 0},
        curveType: 'function',
        backgroundColor: 'none',
        legend: { position: 'bottom' },
        annotations: { style: 'line' },
        colors: ['#15A0C8', '#dc3912'],
        pointSize: 7,
        series: {
            0: { pointShape: 'circle' },
            1: { pointShape: 'triangle' },
            2: { pointShape: 'square' },
            3: { pointShape: 'diamond' },
            4: { pointShape: 'star' },
            5: { pointShape: 'polygon' }
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você pode fazer um array de `$TotalViewsdia`:

```
<?php
$meses = array(
    '01' => 'Janeiro',
    '02' => 'Fevereiro',
    '03' => 'Março',
    '04' => 'Abril',
    '05' => 'Maio',
    '06' => 'Junho',
    '07' => 'Julho',
    '08' => 'Agosto',
    '09' => 'Setembro',
    '10' => 'Outubro',
    '11' => 'Novembro',
    '12' => 'Dezembro'
);

$mes_atual_nome = $meses[date('m')];

$mes_atual = date('m');
$ano_atual = date('Y');

$TotalViewsdia = [];
for ($i=1; $i < 32; $i++) { 
    $ReadViewsDia = ExeRead("pageviews WHERE pageview_dia = '$i' AND pageview_mes = '$mes_atual' AND pageview_ano = '$ano_atual'");
    $numViewsDia = mysqli_num_rows($ReadViewsDia);

    $TotalViewsdia[$i] = ($numViewsDia > 0) ? $numViewsDia : 0;
}
```

No script você pode rodar o foreach listando os valores do array:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Dias', {type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}, 'Todas as visitas', 'Visitas únicas ao site'],

<?php
foreach ($TotalViewsdia as $key => $value) {
?>
    ['Dia <?=$key?>', '', <?= $value ?>, 0],
<?php
}
?>
    ]);
var options = {
chartArea : { top:20 },
vAxis: {minValue: 0},
curveType: 'function',
backgroundColor: 'none',
legend: { position: 'bottom' },
annotations: { style: 'line' },
colors: ['#15A0C8', '#dc3912'],
pointSize: 7,
series: {
0: { pointShape: 'circle' },
1: { pointShape: 'triangle' },
2: { pointShape: 'square' },
3: { pointShape: 'diamond' },
4: { pointShape: 'star' },
5: { pointShape: 'polygon' }
}
};

var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: Fantástico o seu código amigo, só tem um porém, o gráfico é gerado mas os valores aparecem todos como zero "0", dando um "var_dump" percebi que realmente os valores retornados são do tipo "INT" e todos como zero "0";

Comment: Eu observei aqui e não consegui encontrar alguma coisa que estivesse causando este erro (uma vírgula fora do lugar ou outra coisa etc)...Você poderia me dizer se tem algum pequeno erro em sua solução?

Comment: Desde já agradeço sua enorme contribuição.

Comment: Eu sou novato no PHP e o foreach é uma coisa que ainda me complica, o seu código com toda certeza vai me ajudar a entendê-lo um pouco melhor.

Comment: Olá amigo, realmente te um erro e esta nessa linha `$TotalViewsdia[$i] = ($numViewsDia > 0) ? $TotalViewsdia : 0;` o correto seria `$TotalViewsdia[$i] = ($numViewsDia > 0) ? $numViewsDia : 0;`

Comment: eu também editei na resposta para corrigir o erro

Comment: Show!!!...agora funfou!

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo, tô a um tempo aqui olhando o seu código pra aprender mais com esse exemplo prático, vc me ajudou bastante.